# Extract values from string

Tags: c#, xml, string

I've got a string like this:

```
<point srsName="EPSG:4326(WGS84)">
<coordinates>121.7725934555,25.1508396138</coordinates>
```

How can I only get the values from this string, e.g `121.7725934555,25.1508396138`?

Comment: Looks like XML to me.

Comment: XmlDocument or XmlSerializer

Comment: @Fendy: `XDocument` would be easier, assuming this is XML. I don't see a closing `</point>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string is short and you do not need to parse anything else from it, you can use regex:

```
<coordinates>([^,]+),([^<]+)</coordinates>
```

The two capturing groups would get `121.7725934555` and `25.1508396138`.

```
var str = @"<point srsName=""EPSG:4326(WGS84)"">
<coordinates>121.7725934555,25.1508396138</coordinates>";
var m = Regex.Match(str, "<coordinates>([^,]+),([^<]+)</coordinates>");
Console.WriteLine("'{0}' '{1}'", m.Groups[1], m.Groups[2]);
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/bvEqXm).